# What is the connection between PID and feedforward controllers?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, electrical-engineering, control-engineering

They are tightly connected as some concepts of feedforward is based on PID algorithms, and both of them are control systems. But when I see a phrase such as "Feed forwards augment PID control", I'm confused. Can they be used at the same time?

Comment: Feedforward only means that the model is somehow baked in without feedback. The system can also have a feedback mechanism which could be for example a PID.

Comment: @Talgar  A feedforward controller is almost always used with a feedback controller.  Rarely does feedforward controller used by itself [I've never seen that myself].  This could be a useful read: [The Feed Forward Controller](https://controlguru.com/the-feed-forward-controller/).

Comment: @NickAlexeev I have though many of these probably wouldn't qualify as controlled by todays standards.

Comment: @joojaa  I'm curious if there is a universal standard for controllers today.

Comment: @NickAlexeev No, but most of the pure feedforward systems ive seen were purely mechanical. Thus not something where its easy to recognize as  a controller.